# Automatically disable mouse acceleration whenever mouse is plugged

Tags: mouse, udev

I have a laptop and I often use a Logitech G5 mouse with it. I don't like acceleration while using the mouse. Thus I have to disable the acceleration every time I plug the mouse. Is there a way to automatically disable mouse acceleration, whenever I plug my mouse?

Comment: @Braiam isn't it harder for people to find the question lacking those tags?

Comment: Please, read the last 4 questions of this Meta Question http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7819/169736

Comment: I see. Yeah, also search finds it reasonably well without the tags. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it can be done and it's relatively easy to do. You need to create 3 files - a udev rule, and two scripts.

### UDEV Rule

A UDEV rule would detect a mouse plug event and trigger a script whenever the event happens. Create a file under `/etc/udev/rules.d`:

```
sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/42-kill-mouse-accel.rules
```

Paste the following line in it:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="03", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0.0", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/[YOUR_USER_NAME]/.Xauthority", ENV{ID_CLASS}="mouse", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/kill-mouse-accel.sh"
```

**Note the part that says `[YOUR_USER_NAME]`, you have to replace it with your user name.**
Save and exit Gedit.

### Acceleration Script

The acceleration script would be the code triggered by the UDEV rule, which in turn would fork a worker script in the background. The background script would do the actual work. We do that since we want to wait a bit before changing acceleration but we don't want to block UDEV. Create a file under `/usr/local/bin`:

```
sudo gedit /usr/local/bin/kill-mouse-accel.sh
```

Paste the following code in it:

```
#!/bin/bash 

export DISPLAY=${DISPLAY} 
/usr/local/bin/kill-mouse-accel-worker.sh &
```

Save and exit Gedit.

### Background Acceleration Script

This script is where the command disabling mouse acceleration is called. Create a file under `/usr/local/bin`:

```
sudo gedit /usr/local/bin/kill-mouse-accel-worker.sh
```

Paste the following code in it:

```
#!/bin/bash 

sleep 2 

for i in $(xinput list | grep [Mm]ouse | sed -e 's/^.*id=\([0-9]*.\).*$/\1/') 
do 
    echo "Found device: $i" 

    # The command disabling mouse acceleration
    xinput set-ptr-feedback $i 10 1 1 
done
```

Save and exit Gedit.

### Finalization and Testing

Make both scripts executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/kill-mouse-accel.sh /usr/local/bin/kill-mouse-accel-worker.sh
```

Restart UDEV:

```
sudo service udev restart
```

Finally, re-plug your USB mouse and wait for a few seconds. Mouse acceleration should be disabled.

### Credits

Credit goes to the author of the following blog post: http://granjow.net/udev-rules.html

Comment: I don't see difference.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue and I have developed a different solution.

I've written a [Python script that listens for udev events](https://github.com/denilsonsa/small_scripts/blob/master/auto_configure_upon_usb_device_change.py) and runs some commands whenever a device is plugged or unplugged. In my case, [one of the commands disables mouse acceleration](https://github.com/denilsonsa/small_scripts/blob/a368f069dc65b2a40f486c6ccdd8727b268a23b1/xinput_disable_mouse_acceleration.sh). I've choosen this solution because it does not require root permissions, and thus can be applied on any Linux system. I just leave the Python script running in background and don't worry about it anymore.

All the scripts are available at https://github.com/denilsonsa/small_scripts , and they are also copied/mirrored below, for reference.

---

`auto_configure_upon_usb_device_change.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import functools
import os.path
import pyudev
import subprocess
import time

def main():
    BASE_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    path = functools.partial(os.path.join, BASE_PATH)
    call = lambda x, *args: subprocess.call([path(x)] + list(args))

    context = pyudev.Context()
    monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(context)
    monitor.filter_by(subsystem='usb')
    monitor.start()

    call('xinput_disable_mouse_acceleration.sh')

    for device in iter(monitor.poll, None):
        # Wait a short amount of time to let the device get ready.
        time.sleep(0.250)

        call('xinput_disable_mouse_acceleration.sh')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`xinput_disable_mouse_acceleration.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

xsp_microsoft() {
    xinput set-prop 'Microsoft  Microsoft Basic Optical Mouse v2.0 ' "$@"
}
xsp_logitech() {
    xinput set-prop 'Logitech USB Laser Mouse' "$@"
}

xsp_microsoft 'Device Accel Profile' -1
xsp_logitech 'Device Accel Profile' -1

xsp_microsoft 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 1.5
```